# Do two builder patterns exist?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, builder

I am studying design patterns and I found a very confusing thing. What exactly is the builder pattern for? There are two absolutely different purposes I found.

First is what Erich Gamma describes in his book Design Patterns - Elements of Reusable Object Oriented Software (my personal bible). It is a mechanism, how to build complex objects where the Director knows the structure of the built object and uses Builders that know how to build concrete sub-objects. A great stuff how to separate the structure from the concrete building blocks implementation.

I was happy with this explanation until I started to read Effective Java from Joshua Bloch. He describes the builder as a pattern, that can cope with many optional parameters and very effectively solves the problem of a telescopic constructors, for example.

Wikipedia understands the builder pattern as Joshua Bloch as a way how to cope the telescopic constructor http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern. This has absolutely nothing in common with Erich's explanation.

What do I understand wrong?

Comment: from what you say it seems that builder described in Erich Gamma is a factory, but I'm not sure, didn't read that book yet.

Comment: It is a different pattern and this is how Erich describes the difference: "Abstract Factory (87) is similar to Builder in that it too may construct complex objects. The primary difference is
that the Builder pattern focuses on constructing a complex object step by step. Abstract Factory's emphasis is on
families of product objects (either simple or complex). Builder returns the product as a final step, but as far as the
Abstract Factory pattern is concerned, the product gets returned immediately."

Comment: So it is the same pattern in both cases in the end. Ask yourself what problem builder solves, and you will see that both explanations solves it. Patterns are not tied to a specific code, there are various implementations of patterns.

Answer (score 0):

There is really nothing incompatible with what is given by your 3 sources. A builder is a kind-of factory -- you're not directly instantiating the final object.

A builder is a factory that allows a user to be guided through a complex instantiation process where in addition you may want certain properties fixed once set.

So, it's a factory in the sense that it may return 1 of many polymorphic objects. Any one of those could have had who-knows what kind of construction process.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
```

Above is an example. What concrete instance of 'Gson' did you get? Who knows? Who cares?!

I recently implemented a builder that created an instance of a file merger based on a crazy combination of parameters.

```
XEMErger merger = new XEMergerBuilder().build() //return a default auto-detecting merger

XEMErger merger = new XEMergerBuilder.multi().strict(); // return multi-type merger with strict checking
```

As one of the guys who implemented the logic behind this builder, selecting the correct instance was very tricky and leaving it up to an outside user would have been a recipe for misuse.

When the logic for choosing a specific subclass in a factory is crazy and relies on several inputs (sometimes in the context of previous calls) then a builder is the way to go. This is a rarely used pattern so it's easy to misunderstand it